# Not able to write updated value in xml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x, parsing

I'm able to set updated value but it is not written back to xml

```
 xml_doc = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_list = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('JOB')
    for items in item_list:
        if str(items.attributes['JOBNAME'].value) in parsedXmlData:
            old_value = items.attributes['CMDLINE'].value
            print old_value
            items.setAttribute('CMDLINE', parsedXmlData[str(items.attributes['JOBNAME'].value)])
            print "New Value", items.attributes['CMDLINE'].value
```

What exactly I am missing here?

Comment: Please provide your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example by editing your question.

Comment: Let's say in xml on which i am trying modify old_value = items.attributes['CMDLINE'].value is 'abc' and new value which I got from some other mechanism parsedXmlData[str(items.attributes['JOBNAME'].value)] is 'pqr' I want to write 'pqr' on xml. I can see when I do items.setAttribute('CMDLINE', parsedXmlData[str(items.attributes['JOBNAME'].value)]) value is 'pqr' but it is not wriiten back on xml. How I can write new value to xml.